# Intended use of case `this` in anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2016

**Question**

I have just started learning JS/ES7 today, and would like to see if I have understood `this` correct.

Based on the two code snippets below, I suppose the purpose of `this` is that one can choose if one wants to inherit the variables from the parent function?

If that is correct, could there be a legit use case of using `this` in `setInterval()` in the first of the examples?

```
var countup = {
    counter: 0,

    start:function(){
        var countup = this;
        setInterval(function(){
            countup.counter++;
        }, 1000);
    }
};

countup.start();
```

and

```
var countup = {
    counter: 0,

    start:function(){
        setInterval( () => {
            this.counter++;
        }, 1000);
    }
};

countup.start();
```

**Update**

Another way to ask my above question could be:

Can anyone come up with a good use case of `this` inside `setInterval()`?

```
var countup = {
    counter: 0,

    start:function(){
        var countup = this;
        setInterval(function(){
            // insert good use case of `this` inside this function?
            countup.counter++;
        }, 1000);
    }
};

countup.start();
```

Comment: Not for `setInterval`, no, because you know that `this === window` in there, but there are many other cases where a callback might want to use the `this` argument. jQuery being a prime example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think "inherit" is the right word.

Every time a function is called, [a hidden `this` argument](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-built-in-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist) ("the this value", sometimes called the "receiver") is present. The this value depends on how a function is called.

`this` was added to the language to enable Java-like object-orientated syntax. For example:

```js
class Point {
  constructor(x, y) {
   this.x = x
   this.y = y
  }
  getX() {
    return this.x
  }
}
```

...or using a constructor function:

```js
function Point(x, y) {
  this._x = x
  this._y = y
}

Point.prototype.getX = function() {
  return this._x
}
```

So, `this` enables the programmer to conveniently refer to the object on which a function is called as a method:

```
const a = new Point(1, 2);
console.log(a.getX());
```

...but, unfortunately, there is additional complexity around `this` in JavaScript.

The complexity stems from the ability to call functions in ways other than as a method on an object (for full details see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)). For example:

```js
function  myFunction() {
  console.log(this) // `undefined` in strict mode, `window` in non-strict
}
myFunction() // `myFunction` is not called as a method!
```

Your first example provides an example of invoking a function in a way other than as a method: what should the this value be, in the function supplied as a callback to `setInterval`? As it happens, the default value of `this` in functions supplied to `setInterval` is the global object (so `window` in this instance).

...and this explains the idiom we see used in your code: assigning the value of `this` to a variable `that` (I renamed it from "countup" in your example) for the callback to close over. In this way we can refer to the this value of the outer lexical environment, from *within* the callback, whenever it is called.

```js
var countup = {
    counter: 0,
    start: function() {
        var that = this
        setInterval(function() {
            that.counter++
        }, 1000)
    }
}
```

Your second example is doing the same thing, but in more modern JavaScript. Arrow functions always use the this value of the lexical environment in which they are declared (the "lexical this"). So we can do away with the intermediate `that` variable:

```js
var countup = {
    counter: 0,
    start: function() {
        setInterval(() => this.counter++, 1000)
    }
}
```

Inside `setInterval` the default `this` value is the global object, but there is nothing to stop you from making use of another this value using an arrow function, or [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). It is just a reference to an object (or `null`, or `undefined`). So if there is shared state you want to update from `setInterval`, then you can do so via `this`. Whether this is a good idea or not is subjective. Personally I try and avoid `this`, because I think it makes things more complicated, but plenty of developers think the opposite.

In my experience, `this` tends to be used more in codebases using class-based object orientation, because these codebases have methods that frequently need to refer to state on the object against which they were called.

```js
class Clock {
  start() {
    setInterval(() => this.tick(Date()), 1000) // using lexical `this`!
  }
  tick(time) {
    console.log(time)
  }
}
const c = new Clock
c.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, you are assigning the `this` value when the `startup` **function was defined** and assigning it to a variable `countup` and the `this` at that moment gets stored in the `countup` variable which would be referenced by the closure formed by the callback in the `setInterval` function.

If you don't do that then in a `function` the `this` is taken from the context of execution of that function. That means when the `setInterval` will run the `this` will be the global object, as the callback passed to the `setInterval` executes in the global context:

```js
var countup = {
  counter: 0,

  start: function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      //this is not the lexical this, but the context of execution
      //since this.counter is not defined, this would print NaN (undefined + 1 == NaN)
      this.counter++;
      console.log("this == window::true ", this == window, "this.counter::NaN:: ", this.counter);
    }, 1000);
  }
};

countup.start();
```

In the second example, the *arrow function* `() => {}` supplied to the `setInterval` always captures the `this` from the lexical scope, so the `this` is always bound. So this works correctly without manually needing to capture the `this` from the *lexical* scope. But please note that both are anonymous functions i.e. lacks the `name` property, this behavior is nothing to do with the anonymous nature of the functions. It is how they are defined, one is defined using the `function` syntax and the other is an arrow function syntax.

From the Mozilla [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function does not have its own this. The this value of the
>   enclosing lexical scope is used; arrow functions follow the normal
>   variable lookup rules. So while searching for this which is not
>   present in current scope, an arrow function ends up finding the this
>   from its enclosing scope.

Comment: Since the first example allows for two different `this`. Can you think of a use case to use `this` inside `setInterval()`? I have updated OP.

Comment: @SandraSchlichting You have already given a good use case of using `this` in the first example. There you have a function which updates the property on the same object. In order to do so you need the `this` reference which has the property to be updated that you are getting by assigning the lexical `this` to the `countup ` variable. Now when you pass the callback to the `setInterval` the callback forms a *closure* around the scope of the `start` function and captures the `countup` variable which is nothing but the lexical `this`.

Comment: @BenAston Yes it does not, I never said it does, OP is manually assigning the `this` value **when the function was defined** to a variable `countup `. So that when the callback is defined the resulting the closure would have access to that `countup` variable.

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` exists on the global / [WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope) so the value of `this` is bound to that. As the global is unique and accessible throughout the script I don't think there would be any use case for a "bound" function with `setInterval`